# How to convert restsharp code to httpclient which contains file

Tags: c#, httpclient, restsharp

I'm trying to post some data with file uploaded , I have restsharp code to do that but i want to do that with htttpclient

I’ve tried Many time to convert the code but i can't
the challange that i can't upload file with some data using httpclient
this is restsharp code

```
var client = new RestClient("http://hlocal.halalcircleh.com/api/user-update");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------900467662034781824108624");
request.AddHeader("Host", "hlocal.halalcircleh.com");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "token");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"gender\"\r\n\r\n1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\ndv bahaa elden\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"\r\n\r\ndvbahaa2@gmail.com\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"phone\"\r\n\r\n01211484991\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n123456\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password_confirmation\"\r\n\r\n123456\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"\r\n\r\ntest\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var json = jsonConvert.SerializeObject();
var stringContent = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response =  client.PostAsync("http://hlocal.halalcircleh.com/api/user-update",stringContent).Result;

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=-900467662034781824108624");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "hlocal.halalcircleh.com");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "token");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW..........");             
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("multipart/form-data; boundary=......);
```

Comment: Please leave the code tags in, so that your answer is readable.

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't clearly show how a file is included in the request, what exactly are you serializing?

Comment: This answer makes absolutely no sense, why would you add headers **after** sending the request?